Hi i have four old paintings with this signature seal. Just wondering if anyone knows what it says
Just wondering if anyone knows what this stamp seal means on four old paintings i have. Thanks i would appreciate any feedback.

Could it be 齐全伴墨, "Completely (done) with ink" ?, as it makes sense in this context? And also a play on the artist's name as depicted in the seal?

The seal said 伴墨 (accompany ink)
I am sure the last two characters of the writing are also 伴墨, and the first two characters look like 寒金 (cold gold)
